Interpreting simulation results
I've coded a tiny example of how to apply simulation to the TSP, and I am having some problems interpreting the obtained results. So, first, I will describe the proposed procedure, and then point out my questions.
Methodology
I am trying to solve the problem where the costs of a TSP instance is given by a probability distribution, rather than static values. So, I conceived the following procedure to mimic this behavior.


Initially, we consider the TSP instance (the cost matrix).
After, we shuffle the matrix, by generating a new edge cost from a normal distribution centered at the original edge cost and with an STD of rate percent of the original cost. So, if the edge cost is $x$, then the new cost will be given by a random number from the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(x, x \times r)$ where $r$ is a parameter stating the rate of distance from the original cost.
Note that, the resulting matrix may not give a matric graph, therefore we run the Floyd-Wharshall algorithm.
The new TSP instance is then solved by the LKH algorithm.
And the aimed histogram is updated, in such a way that its categories are the obtained optimal costs (over the shuffled matrices) and the frequency is the amount of time the solution appears.

Results
So far, I have obtained the following results.
For instance ch150.

And, for instance berlin52.

Question
Why is the obtained cost distribution resulting as a left-skewed one (when compared to the optimal static cost)? Shouldn't it be around the static cost (the optimal cost of the TSP instance without shuffling)?
Tech. considerations
The code for the experiments is given here.
PS. 1: Seed uniqueness is guaranteed, cf. here.
PS. 2: The above results were attained by performing 100K samplings.

This is probably overly simplistic, but I'll float the idea anyway. Suppose we start with initial arc costs and an initial optimal tour T, and then add random noise (mean 0, symmetric distribution) to cost of one arc. For an arc that belongs to T, the noise can either increase or decrease the cost of T, and thus can either increase or decrease the cost of an optimal tour (particularly if T is the unique optimum to the original problem). For an arc A that does not belong to T, the noise can decrease the cost of an optimal tour (if A becomes cheap enough that a new tour using A beats T) but cannot increase the cost of an optimal tour (because you can stick with T). So there is an inherent asymmetry to changing a single arc cost, and the approach you use to generate a new scenario can be viewed as an aggregation of individual changes.

Thank you for the answer. It makes sense, although I will have to reason more on this. Maybe try to see what happens with a hypergeometric distribution.
